# What's the meaning of "Mek" from the Gentleman "Red town" song?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

The chorus is

> Come mek we go paint the town red
> White sand, cool breeze and sunset
> The destination is freedom from stress
> That’s the getaway, hmm-mmm

Full lyrics can be found on [Muztext](https://fr.muztext.com/lyrics/gentleman-red-town).

I found it weird that google translates me this in "Viens mek on va peindre la ville en rouge" in French.

Is "mek" really somebody's name?

Comment: [**translates this for me**]. mek is mec, which means guy in French. There was a typo. Come on, guy, we're going to paint the town red. That song is terrible. It's hard to tell the original language. The word guy does not appear in the English. What a mess it is.

Comment: I see that [another site has the lyrics as "Come an’ mek mi paint di town red"](https://genius.com/Gentleman-red-town-annotated) in which case it is a dialect pronunciation for **make**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about some badly written song lyrics which won't help anyone learn English. It's off topic.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - 'come mek mi/me _do something_' is Jamaican patois for 'Let's _do something_'. _Moon shine tonight come mek we dance and sing._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In the English version the patois works, but not in the French one: Viens mek on va peindre la ville en rouge"

Comment: @Lambie - in e.g. _allez les mecs_ I've never seen _mec_ as 'patois', in the way that Verlan is, rather just slangy/casual. Originally _un mécanicien_ - a guy who works in a garage, then a tough beefcake type of guy, and these days just a 'bloke'.

Comment: It's perhaps better punctuated "Viens, mec, on va peindre la ville en rouge" but it's regular colloquial French, it's not patois.

Comment: In case it needs clarifying, identifying the Jamaican patois **verb** _mek_ with the colloquial French **noun** _mec_ is _an error_. They are homophones. That's all.

Comment: @StuartF - I'm not sure how to classify _les mecs aiment kiffer les meufs_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Excuse me, Michael. mec is guy, and mek in Jamaican patois is make. Yeah, guys like being **into women**. Sure.

Answer (score 6):

*Mec* or *mek* is a [Jamaican patois pronunciation of "make" or "made"](https://jamaicanpatwah.com/term/mek/1038#.ZDgzbtLMKXI).  Gentleman is a German reggae singer, and reggae is a musical form that originiated in the Caribbean, specifically in Jamaica.  Jamaican patois is a dialect of English spoken on the island. As a non-standard dialect, it doesn't have a standard written form, and there is variation in spelling.

Specifically ["Mek we" is a patois expression meaning "Let's"](https://jamaicanpatwah.com/term/Mek-wi/3632#.ZDg09tLMKXI) Of course Gentleman isn't a native patois speaker (nor am I!) so this may not a natural or idiomatic use in Jamaica.

Google translate is set up to translate English, not patois.

It is probably worth noting at this point that using lyrics, especially lyrics written in patois, as a specific source for learning English is a poor idea.  Normal speech isn't the same as lyrics.

Comment: Older people may remember 'The It Mek', a reggae hit for Desmond Dekker and the Aces in 1969. To say 'it mek' to someone is to say, e.g. 'that's what happens', 'that's what you get'.